# JIRA: How do you create custom logic around a custom field?

Tags: jira, customization

All!  I've been searching for an answer to this question for ages. Hoping somebody is able to help me out here.

**Here is what I want to do:**

1. Create a custom field. (Either a drop-down with a simple [yes/no] or checkbox).
2. Implement logic, based on the value of the custom field, which dictates the next column on the Kanban board the story must be put in.

**Real World Example:**

Here's an example:

1. I create a Drop-Down/Checkbox called: "Business Review Required".
2. I have three columns on my kanban board: "In Progress", "Business Review", "QA"
3. If the value of the "Business Review Required" custom field is 'yes' or 'enabled', then the Story MUST go into the "Business Review" column on my kanban board.
4. If the value of the "Business Review Required" custom field is 'no' or 'disabled', then the Story will be PREVENTED from going into the "Business Review" column, and must go to "QA".

I appreciate any assistance anybody can provide. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Define transitions from the first status to each of the other three statuses
2. Add a condition to each transition to restrict when that transition is valid, e.g. "Business Review Required" custom field is 'yes'

Now only the appropriate transition button will appear.
The problem is that users don't know why the other choices are not shown

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know if the ability to define a Custom Field Condition comes with JIRA by default?  I'm seeing a lot about having to use 3rd party plug-ins for certain conditions and Validators.

Comment: Jira has a small number of conditions when installed but most of the useful ones come from plugins